# How to use PHP 5.6 (or later) on cloudControl?

Tags: php, version, cloudcontrol, symfony

I have a Symfony 3.0 application that I want to deploy on cloudControl. The app is running on the `pinky` stack; my `composer.json` requires PHP >=5.5.9

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    ...
}
```

When I try to push, I get

```
...
-----> WARN: No php version found in composer.json. Falling back to legacy build.
...
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - This package requires php >=5.5.9 but your PHP version (5.4.45) does
      not satisfy that requirement.
```

The [`phpinfo()` of the pinky stack](http://pinky-phpinfo.cloudcontrolled.com/) shows, that PHP 5.6.12 is running.

How do I have to modify my `composer.json` (or any other file in my application) to make this run in PHP 5.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a blog post, about how to use specific PHP versions and extensions.

http://www.paasfinder.com/custom-php-version/

Since all systems are 64bit, you have to use e.g.:

```
{
    "require": {
        "php-64bit": "5.6.12"
    }
}
```